# Connect with a user in SFTP and SSH

Tags: ssh, sftp, chroot

I want to allow a non-root user to log in SFTP with Filezilla (for modify files), in the /home/test folder AND to connect in SSH (for other operations).

I work on a Debian 10.7. Root is the owner of the folder with the rights 755. I am doing my tests with a user in the sftp group

My sshd_config :

```
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp

Match Group sftp
ChrootDirectory /home/test/
ForceCommand internal-sftp
AllowTCPForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
```

So i can connect him to /home/test with Filezilla, but i can't connect him with SSh. The test gives :

```
This service allows sftp connections only.
```

Is it possible to run both ? I don't quite know what to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp

Match Group sftp
ChrootDirectory /home/test/
ForceCommand internal-sftp
AllowTCPForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
```

This configuration is common for restricting users to *only* SFTP access. You indicate that you want to permit both SFTP and plain SSH sessions (command-line access, normally called a "shell" session). A configuration that restricts users to only SFTP is not correct for you.

Your immediate problem is the `ForceCommand internal-sftp` line. This forces the server to start SFTP for any client session. If you want to permit sessions other than SFTP, such as a shell session, then this line shouldn't be present.

Beyond that, consider the other lines:

```
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp
```

A "subsystem sftp" line needs to be in there to permit SFTP. This line is fine. Leave it in.

```
ChrootDirectory /home/test/
```

This line restricts the user to the `/home/test` directory and its subdirectories. It's fine for an SFTP session. But to support shell sessions, the `/home/test` directory would need to be a complete ["chroot"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/542440/how-does-chrootdirectory-and-a-users-home-directory-work-together) directory with device files, shared libraries, and a set of programs that the user is permitted to run. This will be a significant effort to set up and maintain, and it's unusual to restrict command-line users to a chroot environment like this. You most likely don't want this and should remove it.

```
Match Group sftp
AllowTCPForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
```

These lines are fine if that's what you want. The `Match Group` line restricts the following lines to affect users in the "sftp" group. The `AllowTCPForwarding` line prevents these users from forwarding TCP ports. The `X11Forwarding` line prevents these users from forwarding X sessions. If you have a reason to restrict these, then it's fine to leave these lines in.